# Is quickfix compatible with pypy?

Tags: python, pypy, quickfix

I just tried to install package quickfix (1.15.1) under pypy (version 3.8) .

```
pip install quickfix
```

The quickfix installation process was failed with the following warnings and errors:

```
Building wheel for quickfix (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [66 lines of output]
```

,

```
 # include <Python.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

I also tried:

Upgrading pip
some other versions of quickfix (1.14.1, 1.14.2).

I was wondering if there is a solution to this issue and if quickfix is compatible with pypy.

Comment: You need to install Python’s development libraries.

Comment: To be more specific, you need to install the pypy-specific dev libraries, most likely named `pypy-dev` or `pypy3-dev` depending on the distro.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.

I just installed pypy3-dev. The quickfix installation process was failed again . The output contains the following errors: 


 C++/QuickfixPython.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void SwigDirector_Application::onCreate(const FIX::SessionID&)’:
      C++/QuickfixPython.cpp:5968:11: error: ‘Py_Exit’ was not declared in this scope
                 Py_Exit(1);

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be related to the library. Try installing the wheel file instead.

1. Click here on the link [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix)
   and download the version of wheel file for quickfix by checking your python version.
2. If it is 3.7 version then select a wheel file quickfix‑1.15.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
3. Select the directory in CMD in which the file is downloaded and install it as `pip install quickfix‑1.15.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Is there a wheel file compatible with ubuntu?

Comment: I don't believe it is needed in ubuntu. Please try using pip install quickfix.

Comment: The question is about PyPy, and these are CPython wheels.